# Send a php variable in a text email as plain text

Tags: php, ajax, email, text

I am passing a variable with Ajax to my php file and then sending both a normal email and a text. The variable is an array that is looping like this:

`echo "<p class='names'>" . $give. " give to ".$receiving . "</p>";`

Therefor it works well for my normal email, but in the SMS text, it is showing up like:

`<p class='names'>A give to B . "</p>"`

I want the text version to just show `A give to B`

In my php file, the variable is written like `$nameOutput = $_POST['nameOutput'];`. Is there a function that I could assign to `$nameOutput` later in the file, before the text code to rewrite the variable to only render the text, but with a line break per loop?

So something like this:

`A give to B`

`B give to C`

Anyone know if this is possible?

Code:

```
$nameOutput = $_POST['nameOutput'];
$email_send = $_POST['email'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
$carrier    = $_POST['carrier'];
```

Text part later in code

```
$nameOutput = strip_tags($nameOutput, '<br>');
$to_text = $phone."@".$carrier;
$from_text = "paul@optimumwebdesigns.com";
$message = "Here are your results!" . "<br>" . $nameOutput;
$headers = "From: $from\n";
mail($to_text, '', $message, $headers);
```

`$nameOutput` renders the following:

```
Paul & Becky give to Ashley & Jeric
Keith & Jackie give to Rob & Savannah
Dave & Lauren give to Paul & Becky
Ashley & Jeric give to Dave & Lauren
Rob & Savannah give to Keith & Jackie
```

Newest Code:

```
$breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");
$nameOutput = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $nameOutput);
$nameOutput = strip_tags($nameOutput);
//$nameOutput = strip_tags($nameOutput, '\r\n');
$to_text = $phone."@".$carrier;
$from_text = "paul@optimumwebdesigns.com";
$message = "Here are your results!" . "<br>" . $nameOutput;
$headers = "From: $from\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
mail($to_text, '', $message, $headers);
```

**Edit icecub:**
Just to clerify for any future readers: He's talking about plain text SMS messages. Not emails!

Comment: First do something like `$breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>"); $nameOutput = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $nameOutput);`. Then  [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) like `$nameOutput = strip_tags($nameOutput);`

Comment: But I would advise you to post your actual code so I can see exactly how it works and give you an answer that I can actually test first.

Comment: @icecub I added the php code. Let me know if you need any more of it (like the Ajax part or how the code is created). I added the `strip_tags` function that you brought up earlier. It got rid of the code, but it still shows `&amps` for "&" and the `<br>` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Could you add an example? I mean a full one. Just so I can see what exactly needs to be stripped away

Comment: @icecub I added the text that will render. Just each line will be wrapped in the paragraph tags.

Comment: And ye, you shouldn't add `<br>` as an allowed tag to `strip_tags()`. You need to replace it with `\r\n` for plain text email. If you check my first comment (I've edited it), you'll see what I mean.

Comment: And you should add this to `$headers`: `$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";`. That should fix the problem with the & sign.

Comment: @icecub I just made the changes you recommended and added my newest code to my question. It still isn't adding breakers and still does the `&amp`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159785/discussion-between-icecub-and-paul).

Comment: I've opened up a chat so the comments dont become to long. We should continue there.